# Remove margin and padding from floating table header

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am sticking a `thead` after scroll through it. My problem is that it offsets when I change the position from `static` to `absolute`. On the change it adds `margin` and `padding` to the `thead` like so:

[image]
[image]

I have tried to use CSS to fix it with:

```
<thead id='tableHeader' style="margin:0;border:0;padding:0;">
</thead>
```

I want to remove the margin and padding to keep the original dimensions of the table header (1871 * 37)

Comment: can you post a working example? with the rest of your css and html?

Comment: That inspector layout diagram doesn't indicate there's _any_ margin or padding on that element.

Comment: @JoshBurgess , Why do the boxes around the element change on scroll if they don't indicate a change? Thank you for the reply. Any idea what could cause it?

Comment: Once you add `position:absolute` to the `thead`, it loses the context of the table as its been taken out of the document flow.  Since it no longer has the `table` for its context, it's going to size itself how it sees fit.  Try adding `display: block`, `width: 1759px; /* Or whatever your table width is */` as additional parameters when you apply the `position: absolute;`

Comment: @JoshBurgess , the width changes depending on data, should i store table width on load before making the position absolute?

Comment: Or use jQuery like so: `$('#tableHeader').width($('table#tableID').width())`, or pure JS if you're not using jQuery: `document.querySelector('#tableHeader').style.width = document.querySelector('table#tableID').style.width;`

Comment: @JoshBurgess , please add this as an answer. It works much better now with the width fix. I just need to align the text inside the thead when floating it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you add `position:absolute` to the `thead`, it loses the context of the `table` as its been taken out of the document flow. Since it no longer has the `table` for its context, it's going to size itself how it sees fit. Try adding

```
width: 1759px; /* Or whatever your table width is */
```

as additional parameters when you apply the position: absolute;

To fix sizing issues for dynamically sized tables, you can use jQuery like so:

```
 $('#tableHeader').width($('table#tableID').width()),
```

or pure JS if you're not using jQuery:

```
 document.querySelector('#tableHeader').style.width = document.querySelector('table#tableID').style.width;
```